# Making Python Enums safe for interactive work in which one may execute the file multiple times

Tags: python, enums, singleton, metaprogramming, python-interactive

If I'm doing interactive work in Python and have an `Enum` that looks like this

```
from enum import Enum
class UnsafeColor(Enum):
     RED = 1
     GREEN = 2
     BLUE = 3
```

I may do

```
[In]: socks = UnsafeColor.RED
<rerun file>
[In]: shoes = UnsafeColor.RED
[In]: socks == shoes
[Out]: False
```

This is kind of surprising, but the problem is that rerunning the file has created a new `UnsafeColor` class with members that is not equal to the old one. I can avoid this by doing something like

```
from functools import lru_cache
try:
    get_interactive_safe_enum
except NameError as e:
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def get_interactive_safe_enum(*args, **kwargs):
        return Enum(*args, **kwargs)

SafeColor = get_interactive_safe_enum("SafeColor", "RED GREEN BLUE")
```

Now the following works as expected:

```
[In]: hat = SafeColor.RED
<rerun file>
[In]: shirt = SafeColor.RED
[In]: hat == shirt
[Out]: True
```

This works, but it's not winning any awards. There appears to be lots of singleton and metaclass magic going on with `Enum`, so I wonder, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are experiencing is the `<rerun file>` step.  In Python 2 that was a built-in spelled `reload()` and in Python 3 it was hidden away in a module because it was an attractive nuisance -- for precisely the reasons you state above.

Python is not designed to have any of its modules "rerun", and you will find that every module with singletons that were saved before the rerun (such as your socks above) will have copies in the new, rerun file (your shoes above).

In other words, this is not an `Enum` problem -- it's the way Python is designed.  If you rerun a module, take care to update anything you have previously saved -- module variables, functions, classes, and singletons.

---

To add some hopefully helpful advice -- keep your constants and things that won't need to be reloaded in their own file; when the `<rerun file>` get's rerun it will still be importing the already-run-and-not-run-again constants file, and your Enums and other constants will be the same.

Comment: I do this `<rerun file>` business with `<F5>` in Spyder. Your advice sounds like a practical way to deal with this that is less involved than creating a special `Enum` variant.